# Spring Integration outbound-gateway using authentication token

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-integration, basic-authentication

I need to call different REST web services, all of them require a previous authentication against a service using Username and Password. Once authenticated, I obtain a token which allows me to call these web services.
I would like to know what would be the best approach using Spring Integration and "int-http:outbound-gateway" endpoints, also how to renew the token if it's expired.

Thanks,
JC

Comment: Looks like you need `OAuth` (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) and inject its `OAuthRestTemplate` into the `<nt-http:outbound-gateway">`.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan, do you have any working sample? I've tried "<oauth:rest-template ...>" but I am getting a "No Scope registered for scope 'session'".